# How to write in a file a paragraph with not the same value of other

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have some information repeated (they have the same [ISBN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)), so I want to write only the information that does not already exist on the file. 
I have the following code:

```
c = open('e.txt','r')
message=c.read()
d=open('download.txt','a')
for i in range(1,len(message)):  
    if 'title' in message:              
        parag=message.split('book')[i] #to get the paragraph (that starts with 'title')
        text='title'+parag
        for x in range(0,len(text)):
            isbn=[s[8:-1] for s in text.split() if s.startswith("isbn")]
            d.write(isbn)
            if sid not in  #####how??    
                d.close
c.close
```

I can get the ISBN of all the books but I dont know how to compare them with the ones that already exist in 'download.txt' because I cant read this `.txt` file...

Comment: how e.txt looks? Can you give some example data. **Note** : close file outside the loop.

Comment: @SumitJha yes. It's like:                                                                                   "book title:xxxxxxxxxxxx, author:xxxxxxxxxxx, category: xxxxxxxxxxxx, isbn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                                                                           book title:xxxxxxxxxxxx, author:xxxxxxxxxxx, category: xxxxxxxxxxxx, isbn: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  etc." Each book has got some lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first read the file `download.txt` and store all data in [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) (suppress duplicate) than you can subtract the already exists ISBN data from the new data and write it to file

a pseudo snippet

```
isbn_exists = set()
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    isbn_data = #get data from line
    isbn_exists.add(isbn_data)


isbn_from_message = set()
for data in message:
  isbn_from_message.add(data)

isbn_to_write = isbn_from_message - isbn_exists

with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
  for data in isbn_to_write:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a list of the isbn already written in the file by doing:

```
already_written_isbn.append(isbn)
```

Where already_written_isbn is a list.

And compare the new isbn with number present in the list and write them into the file if aren't in the list

```
if isbn not in already_written_isbn:
        write_it_in_the_file
```

If there are some record already present in the "download.txt" before you start writing new record, read the file at the start and iterate over all the records to find all the isbn numbers and append them to the already_written_isbn list.